# Mimic ABNewPersonViewController UI

Tags: iphone, layout, abaddressbook

I'd like to replicate the iOS 4.x ABNewPersonViewController UI layout (see [link text](http://www.fahimullah.com/stuff/4/contact.png)) in a custom view but I'm unsure about the best way to achieve this. I was thinking of a single grouped UITableView, but what about the first section? How do I achieve the smaller cells (first,last,company)? And finally the "add photo canvas" is it just a sub UIView with a background image for the shadow and the rounded border or can this be done programmatically?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your idea about a single grouped UITableView could work.  The way to get the smaller cells as well as the photo cell would be to subclass UITableViewCell and create it like that. and yes the photo canvus is just a custom UIView added on top of the UITableView. I'm not sure i see the point of rolling your own here, but thats how i'd start.  Also i think i recall seeing a tutorial on how to build this page..try googling for it.